# When I pop from stack, the value is deleted; why?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, stack-memory

```
; SP is at 0100h
mov  ax, 1234h
push ax
pop  ax
sub  sp, 2
```

The value in `SS:00FE` is no longer 1234h. It has become 3302h. Why is this?
Even without the `sub sp, 2` instruction, just scrolling down to `SS:00FE`, it's 3302h.

After `push ax`, `SP` = 00FEh
After `pop ax`, `SP` = 0100h
After `sub sp, 2`, `SP` = 00FEh

Comment: It's getting clobbered by a hardware interrupt most likely.

Answer (score 4):

The value below stack at `SS:SP-2` is not deleted, but it may be overwritten by another process soon. In real CPU mode the stack is shared with interrupts and other CPU threads running concurrently, for instance by debugger.
Whenever you press a key to scroll down, CPU will push flags, CS and IP on your stack, overwriting the previous value `1234`.

Comment: so after pop i cant get the value anymore from the stack in the address that i was push before ? after cpu do sp = sp + 2 (after pop) , we cant go back ? and get the value ?

Comment: @salayivany: Not reliably, no.  So just don't design your program that way.  Don't pop a value off the stack, or increment the stack pointer past it, until you no longer need to have that value there.